# How to use an invocation used in a previously deleted project?

Tags: actions-on-google

I did some tests with Actions on Google but it was with the wrong account so I deleted the project. Once I created the new one with the good account, I discovered that the invocation isn't deleted so I can't use it anymore.

Did I miss something to get it completely deleted?

I've received the mail about the 24h hour to recover the project but it's been more than 24h now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me. Support told me that there was a way to "undo" the project deletion and once un-deleted I could change the name so that the old one could be re-used. I forget the details but that option wasn't available for me. They told me I could wait a month or so until the project was physically deleted from their cloud or I could submit a ticket to delete it and wait a week. That's what I did.